# Confused about the structure of this sentence

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

I have difficulty deciphering the meaning and structure of the bold sentence below

> 遠くから、近くから、無数に折り重なる波音を風が運んできた。**曇天に白点ひとつ、さみしく鳴く春かもめが、雪の名残ひとひら、まだ冷たい三月の風だった。**

This sentence contains lots of commas so it looks like there are multiple smaller sentences combined into one. I'm uncertain about the が after 春かもめ. It marks subject for what?

Also, I don't understand the meaning of 白点 here.

Comment: Assuming you have copied it correctly, I think this is an intentional [anacoluthon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluthon). If you were confused and read this twice, that's the author's intent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost like a prose poem at best, and not really parsable as a sentence.

白点 should be simply *a white dot* referring to the seagull or snowflake (or both even if inconsistent with ひとつ).

One possible interpretation:

> 曇天に白点ひとつ、さみしく鳴く春かもめが、

Here かもめ is the subject for some missing verb modified by 曇天に白点ひとつ: *A spring seagull crying sadly (flies like) a white dot in the cloudy sky*.

> 雪の名残ひとひら、まだ冷たい三月の風だった。

Here both are noun phrases describing the situation: *A snowflake (in the air), (there was) March wind which was still cold.*

---

Another possibility is to consider literally かもめが as  subject for 三月の風だった: *A spring seagull crying sadly, (which looks like) white dot in the cloudy sky, with a snowflake, was the cold March wind.*

Anyway it is a description of a scenery with seagull and snow in the cold wind.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like multiple other interpretation are possible.